# UIrefreshcontrol with an asynchronous request

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a `tableView` where I need to implement a `UIRefreshController`. This works fine. What I want is when I pull up and refresh, it needs to do the request again. At the moment there is to an issue when I remove the fixtures objects, but if I don't it will just add the same fixtures which are already there.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[self firstRequest]; //is the request
```

The code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.theTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
        [fixtures removeAllObjects];

    [self firstRequest];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

The problem is everytime i reload it does add the duplicates and when i use

```
       [fixtures removeAllObjects];
```

It gives me following error:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: You don't describe what the issue actually is...

Comment: Do you reload table view data when you finish your request (when you have the data from the web)?